# How to validate graphql in gatsby blog site

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

I am trying to build a blog site in Gatsby and everything was working perfectly until I delete my fake tester blog posts.

My error is :

```
gatsby-node.js" threw an error while running the createPages lifecycle:

Cannot query field "frontmatter" on type "MarkdownRemark".

GraphQL request:8:13
7 |             id
8 |             frontmatter {
  |             ^
9 |               path
```

So my question is how do I make sure this is valid before continuing?

```js
    const { createPage } = actions;

    const postTemplate = path.resolve('src/templates/blog-post.js');

    return graphql(`
    {
      allMarkdownRemark {
        edges {
          node {
            html
            id
            frontmatter {
              path
              title
              date
              featuredImage
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `).then((res) => {
        if (res.errors) {
            return Promise.reject(res.errors);
        }

        if (res.data === undefined) {//Validation attempt
            return;
        }
        res.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
            createPage({
                path      : node.frontmatter.path,
                component : postTemplate
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Do you have any markdown files?

Comment: I did have and it worked fine. But they were tester blog posts. I'm trying to figure out where to skip over the createpages code if I **dont** have any markdown files.

Comment: This could be relevant https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization/

Comment: This seems like one of these `code challenges` that you spend time on and then never need again. Be pragmatic. As soon as you write your first blog post, will there ever be a moment in time when this error will occur again?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are telling gatsby where your markdown content files live

in your `gatsby-config.js`, make sure the plugins array contains the following:

```
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/content`,
        name: 'content',
      },
    },
```

which is just an example if your markdown lives in a content directory